# Split Spark Dataset into equal number of datasets in Spark 3.1 with java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a dataset with many no of rows, and I'm performing collect_list operation in that dataset. I got error like `Cannot grow BufferHolder; exceeds size limitation` .
this is because my collect_list result column size exceeds 2GB. So I wish to split this dataset into multiple dataset and trying to perform the same collect_list opration on that(to reduce col size). Trying [this](https://kb.databricks.com/sql/cannot-grow-bufferholder-exceeds-size.html) suggested fix . How can I achieve that.

This is my sample dataset and sample code.

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| abc|   A|
| abc|   B|
| cde|   B|
| cde|   C|
| efg|   A|
+----+----+

public static Dataset<Row> getData(){
      Dataset<Row> = myDataset;
      return myDataset.groupBy(col("col1")).agg(collect_list(col("col2")));
}
```

and the result is

```
+----+-------+
|col1|col2   |
+----+-------+
| abc|[A,B]  |
| cde|[B,C]  |
| efg|[A]    |
+----+-------+
```

How can i do the same logic by spliting it into multiple datasets? iam using spark 3.1 with java.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting the same issue even with `collect_set()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [randomSplit()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#randomSplit-double:A-long-) or [randomSplitAsList()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#randomSplitAsList-double:A-long-) method to split one dataset into multiple datasets. You can read about this method in detail [here](https://medium.com/udemy-engineering/pyspark-under-the-hood-randomsplit-and-sample-inconsistencies-examined-7c6ec62644bc).

Above mentioned methods will return array/list of datasets, you can iterate and perform `groupBy` and `union` to get desired result.

```
   public static Dataset<Row> getData(Dataset<Row>[] myDataset) {

       // Start Empty dataframe with col1 as string and col2 as array to hold union result
        Dataset<Row> tempDS = SparkSession.active().emptyDataFrame().selectExpr("'' col1", "array() col2");
        
        for (Dataset<Row> ds : myDataset) {

            tempDS = tempDS.union(ds.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_list("col2").alias("col2")));

        }
        return  tempDS;
    }
```